# ng-repeat force a rerender

Tags: angularjs, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know how ngRepeat uses hash keys to not rerender elements,
I am storing a simple array of strings, and I would like to force the re render of the dom , is there a simple way to do it?

to force ng-repeat to re render itself even though my string array havn't changed?

Why :

```
$scope.image = "image/jpg..."
$scope.confs = ['glow','sepia','brighten']

<div ng-repeat="conf in confs">
   <div my-directive="conf">
</div>
```

I want to rerun the ng-repeat when the image changes, not when the conf change

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit. If your array hasn't changed, what's the point in re-rendering it? The result will be identical.

Comment: curious why you would ever need to do this? can try `$apply` but if nothing changed in model angular likely won't do anything

Comment: You still haven't explained *why* you want to reexecute the ng-repeat, and why it would produce a different result.

Comment: because the $scope.image has changed, the configuration is still the same but its not the same image, so my-directive is applied on the wrong image.

ng-repeat will only change if $scope.confs changes, but i want it to re render when $sope.image changes :/

Comment: Could you show your directive? -- The issue could probably be solved by tweaking it a bit.

Comment: +1 to @arturgrzesiak: ng-repeat is fine. What isn't fine ir my-directive: it should watch the image.

Comment: why aren't you just passing the image into directive as an attribute? Show directive code

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you don't actually want `ng-repeat` to rerender, because it will produce exactly the same output: three `my-directive` divs.  Howeer, you DO want all `my-directive`s to rerender, because something they depend on has changed.

What you can do in your directive is set up a `$watch` on your scope.  For example, in `my-directive`'s `link` function,

```
scope.$watch( 
             function thingToWatch(){ return $scope.image; },
             function whatToDo(image){ .../*your code using image here*/... }
);
```

Now, when $scope.image changes, your directives will all update themselves.